# Unable to instantiate a Behavior in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am rather new (very new, in-fact less than 8 hrs new) to Unity 3D.

As it turns out, my newness to Unity has posed me with a rather weird problem. Consider two Behaviors below:

Behavior `CamCaptureDialogBehavior`:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class CamCaptureDialogBehavior : MonoBehaviour
{
        // 200x300 px window will apear in the center of the screen.
        private Rect windowRect = new Rect ((Screen.width - 200) / 2, (Screen.height - 300) / 2, 200, 300);
        // Only show it if needed.
        private bool show = false;

        public CamCaptureDialogBehavior ()
        {
        }
        // Use this for initialization
        void Start ()
        {

        }

        void OnGUI ()
        {
                if (show)
                        windowRect = GUI.Window (0, windowRect, DialogWindow, "Game Over");
        }

        void DialogWindow (int windowID)
        {
                float y = 20;
                GUI.Label (new Rect (5, y, windowRect.width, 20), "Title goes here");

                if (GUI.Button (new Rect (5, y, windowRect.width - 10, 20), "Ok")) {
                        Application.LoadLevel (0);
                        show = false;
                }
        }

        // To open the dialogue from outside of the script.
        public void Open ()
        {
                show = true;
        }
        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update ()
        {

        }
}
```

Behavior: `PictureButtonBehavior`:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
using System.Collections;

public class PictureButtonBehavior : MonoBehaviour
{
        private bool displayedGUI = false;
        private bool ShowThisGUI = false;

        void Start ()
        {
        }

        void Update ()
        {
                if (displayedGUI == true) {
                        Debug.Log (string.Format ("displayedGUI = {0}\r\n", displayedGUI));
                        displayedGUI = false;
                        ShowThisGUI = false;
                }
        }

        void OnGUI ()
        {
                if (ShowThisGUI) {
                        Debug.Log (string.Format ("ShowThisGUI = {0}\r\n", ShowThisGUI));
                        displayedGUI = true;
                        ShowThisGUI = false;
                        CamCaptureDialogBehavior ccdb = new CamCaptureDialogBehavior ();
                        if (ccdb != null) {
                                ccdb.enabled = true;
                                ccdb.Open ();
                        }
                }
        }

        public void OnClick ()
        {
                ShowThisGUI = true;
        }
}
```

At `CamCaptureDialogBehavior ccdb = new CamCaptureDialogBehavior ();`, `ccdb` is always `null`.

Is there a unqiue way to instantiate classes in Unity/Mono?

or, How can I instantiate `CamCaptureDialogBehavior` in `PictureButtonBehavior` and be able to display the dialog represented by `CamCaptureDialogBehavior`.

Comment: If it derives from Monobehaviour, don't use new. Use intiantiate -> http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html

Comment: I tried using initiate, but to use initiate, I need to have an initiated value in the first place. It still returns me null.

Comment: You can use Resources.Load if you don't have an instance to clone :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call `new` on `MonoBehaviours`.

You can instantiate prefabs that have the script attached to them.

```
GameObject g = Instantiate(prefab) as GameObject;
```

Or you can add them to an already existing GameObject.

```
gameObject.AddComponent<ScriptName>();
```

---

Next you will ask *what is a prefab*. It is something very simple, yet very powerful in Unity. [Short tutorial](http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/editor/prefabs-concept-usage) on how to make one.

> You can create a prefab by selecting **Asset > Create Prefab** and then
>   dragging an object from the scene onto the “empty” prefab asset that
>   appears. Simply dragging the prefab asset from the project view to the
>   scene view will then create instances of the prefab.

Comment: I couldn't get this to work (am too new :P) but thanks for pointing me to the right resources. I have fixed the issue but creating widows dynamically.